# marshal Map<String, String> to .xml

Tags: java, xml, jaxb

If I have Map setup like:

```
map.put("foo", "123");
map.put("bar", "456");
map.put("baz", "789");
```

then I want to do something like:

```
  for (String key : map.keySet().toArray(new String[0])) {
    // marshall out to .xml a tag with the name key and the
    // value map.get(key)
  }
```

So what it will marshal out is something like:

```
<map>
  <foo>123</foo>
  <bar>456</bar>
  <baz>789</baz>
</map>
```

Can I do this with some fancy JAXB annotations or is there something else that lends it self to dynamic element names?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use JAXB? I've never used that, but I have had a lot of success with [XStream](http://xstream.codehaus.org/). It's very flexible so you to get the XML you want.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with straight SAX output, much easier since I really didnt want to do O/X mapping anyway. I was really try to avoid writing code :)

Answer (score 0):

like,

```
  for (String key : map.keySet()) {
      System.out.printf("<%s>%s</%s>", key, map.get(key), key);
  }
```

??

Comment: You might want to escape your outputs as per the XML specification.

Comment: it's not hard to escape the only four special chars, <>&"